# JavaScript replace is not working if second argument is again a replace method

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am playing with JavaScript string function and was trying to replace a string like below

```
Actual String : 'Microsoft' 
Replace with :  '\'$\'' is not defined
```

I tried a simple replace like

```
"Microsoft".replace("Microsoft","\'$\' is not defined");
```

and it results

```
' is not defined.
```

But I want to preserve $ sign so thought to write another function which will preserve the $ and return the string; and the same string would be the second parameter for the actual replace method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p id="demo">Microsoft</p>
<p id="test"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function stripslashes(str) {
    str=str.replace("/\\'/g",'');
    return str;
}
function myFunction() {
    var newStr = stripslashes('\'$\' is not defined.');
    var res = "Microsoft".replace("Microsoft",newStr);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = newStr;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working, can anyone help me with it ?

Comment: Umm, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Your ``\`` in the original string are being parsed away by JS when the assignment statement is executed.

Comment: "Microsoft".replace(/(Microsoft)/,"\'$1\' is not defined");

Answer (score 1):

`$'` is a speical token for `String.replace`:

> $' Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.

You need to use `$$` to insert a literal `$`.

```
"Microsoft".replace("Microsoft","'$$' is not defined");
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Also: `"\'$\' is not defined"` is the same as `"'$' is not defined"`, and the slashes do nothing

Comment: this doesn't create the string he wants `'\'$\'' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

```
"Microsoft".replace("Microsoft","\\'$\\' is not defined");
```

Comment: I'm sure he doesn't want to have any backslashes present in his result.

Comment: look at his question: Actual String : 'Microsoft' 
Replace with :  '\'$\'' is not defined .. the answer merits a downvote if its wrong, this gives him what he asked for

Comment: I don't know, we'd need a comment from the OP for on that. However, he explicitly tries to use a `stripSlashes()` function… None of the downvotes is from me, sorry.

Comment: no worries @Bergi :) i totally agree with you .. we need to hear back from the OP

Comment: My actual problem is, '\'$\'  is not defined' is a result of parser   and that parser does one more thing like '{content}'.replace('{content}','\'\$\'is not defined'); When it tries to replace it replaces " ' " only as $ has special meaning in replace. So my entire thought process was,

'{content}'.replace('{content}', '\'$\' is not defined'.replace('\'$\'','$') );